# HTML Email Portrait to Landscape issue

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

I've been trying to tackle responsive design in emails and I am just having one problem. The email displays as it should in portrait and landscape view initially. However, when I go from landscape back to portrait, it does not display correctly. It squeezes the content from the landscape view into the portrait view. Any suggestions?

Here is the link: http://www3.universitybusiness.com/mailing/UBTech/2013/vendor1001.html

Info I forgot to add: I am trying to view it on the Android 2.3 native browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting your viewport metatag like this should make it work on the browser:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

HOWEVER, you should definitely test this on email clients, not on the browser. Gmail mobile, like his desktop counterpart, is the hardest one to get right.

Comment: Thank you! I finally realized my issue was that I was setting the media query incorrectly.